# How change Leading background color flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on Flutter project . i fetch  a list of data from server like this :

```
{
                    "id": 39,
                    "user_id": 53,
                    "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265246,
                    "boxName": "boxt germany",
                    "alert_date": "2021-05-30",
                    "alert_time": "09:40:00",
                    "alert_description": "Panne batterie",
                    "alert_level": "danger"
                }
```

After that i create ListTile to display these data like this :

[image]

My goal is how to add leading background color instead of back button . the background color change depends "alert level" value .
NB : Leading contains only background color

```
alert level = danger ==> background color of leading is red.
alert level = warning  ==> background color of leading is yellow.
alert level = normal ==> background color of leading is blue.
```

My code :

```
   if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.alerts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var boxName = snapshot.data.alerts[index].boxName;
                      var date = snapshot.data.alerts[index].alertDate;
                      var description =
                          snapshot.data.alerts[index].alertDescription;
                      var alert = snapshot.data.alerts[index].alertLevel;
    
                      return Card(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new ListTile(
                              title: Text("$date"),
                              subtitle: Text("$description"),
                              trailing: Text("$boxName"),
                              // leading: BackButton(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int colorState = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color;
    switch (colorState) {
      case 0:
        color = Colors.red;
        break;
      case 1:
        color = Colors.yellow;
        break;
      case 2:
        color = Colors.green;
        break;
      default:
        color = Colors.grey;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Data"),
              subtitle: Text("Description"),
              trailing: Text("BoxName"),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.error,
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Data"),
              subtitle: Text("Description"),
              trailing: Text("BoxName"),
              leading: Container(
                color: color,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => colorState = (colorState + 1) % 3),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using an icon would give you the ability to also indicate the alert level by icon.

Comment: i have user with warning status but it show me red ??

Comment: I don't need floatingActionButton. i want to dispaly error icon with suitable color from server .@OnkelZukunft

Comment: @Sarvesh Dalvi any help

Comment: You need to put the `switch` statement into your code. After you get the alert level from the snapshot and use the alert level to determine the color.

Comment: can you help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67847979/fetch-data-null-for-notification-flutter . @OnkelZukunft